# To Display map from array of latlng I got error: "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined"

Tags: angular, google-maps

I have an array of latlng from which I want to show map on my angular component. I used `QueryList<ElementRef>`, but it is throwing me **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined**

In index.html, at last of the body tag I applied maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js with defer keyword.

Here is my code:

```
@ViewChildren('gmap') gmapElement: QueryList<ElementRef>;


ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if(this.location && this.location.length) {
        this.location.forEach(location => {
          this.gmapElement.forEach(mapToDisplay => {
            const latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude);
            var mapProp = {
              center: latlng,
              zoom: 15,
              // mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            console.log('prop... ',mapToDisplay.nativeElement);
            this.map = new google.maps.Map(mapToDisplay.nativeElement, mapProp);
          })
        })
      }
    }, 5000)
  }
```

In template file,

```
<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5" *ngFor="let location of locations" style="border: solid black 1px">
    <ng-template #gmap class="g-map"></ng-template>
</div>
```

It is throwing me

> "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined".

Please help me out

Comment: Use `div` instead of `ng-template`.

Comment: Okay.. Thank you @pindev.. It is showing me Google map.. But as I have array of latlng it is showing me last latlng..

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd follow up for anyone curious as to why replacing `ng-template` with `div` was the fix:

Per the Angular [docs](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives):

```
The <ng-template> is an Angular element for rendering HTML. It is never displayed 
directly. In fact, before rendering the view, Angular replaces the <ng-template> and 
its contents with a comment.
```

So #gmap template reference variable is never displayed, and so is never picked up in the ViewChildren.

Comment: Yes, right @Jesse. I was trying to display this since last two days and by replacing ng-template with div started showing map. Thank you for addressing this..

Comment: Can you @Jesse help me out from it that from array of latlng and  querylist I am getting only last lat lng. For example if the array length is 3 then, map is showing 3 times but with last latlng value.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote the code to loop and create the gmap inside the location loop. That's why all the maps are using same location.

Try out the following code.

```
this.gmapElement.forEach((mapToDisplay, index) => {
  const location = this.location[index];
  const latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude);
  var mapProp = {
    center: latlng,
    zoom: 15,
    // mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  console.log('prop... ',mapToDisplay.nativeElement);
  this.map = new google.maps.Map(mapToDisplay.nativeElement, mapProp);
});
```

Comment: Oh!! Yes.. location loop can be refactoring.. Thank you so much @pindev.. You saved me..